# When using the particle system, some assets don't use their alpha channel (Weird Pixels and Black Planes)

Tags: texturing, particles, transparency, shadows

I'm rendering a scene that I created with some assets and trees from [Sapling Tree Gen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/sapling.html). But in my rendering there are these weird pixels/shadows and when I look closely I notice that some bushes don't seem to use their alpha channel. I only use 3 types of bushes in the rendering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this happens because cycles sets a limit on how many times transparency can overlap before it stops calculating; by default it's set to 8. Anything above 8 layers of transparency will just render as black. This can be increased in the render tab under Light Paths > Max Bounces > "Transparent"

I setup a little scene here that visualizes it. It's just a plane with an array modifier and a principled shader with its alpha set to 0.2

[image]