# Using alpha textures with particles

Tags: texturing, particles, transparency

I have a particle system set to render as object.
The object has an image texture that is a white dot that fades to black. This texture is also the alpha channel.
The alpha matte works fine on the original object, i.e. it fades to nothing around the edges.
However, when this same object appears in the particle system, I don't get any transparency at all. It fades to black instead of to transparent.
Any reason the particles might be doing this?

Comment: Would you mind give us more information, like which render engine you use, how is the material setup, the particle system settings etc. and show us some screenshots? Because the only thing I get from this is you have an object with some alpha transparency but using it as particle makes it opaque. If I recreate this in some way, it works as expected with transparency. So we need a lot more details to see what you did differently, or even better load up your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Comment: Answering my own question! It turned out this was the fix: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253028/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gordon Brinkmann! I should have mentioned I am using Cycles and the latest version of Blender 3.4.1. The fix turned out to be changing the Transparent number in the Cycles settings to match the number of particle.