# Some of hair particles are black (Cycles render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, transparency, hair

I have an issue. I have Particle system and I try to render feathers with Cycle render but some of the feathers are displayed black. Feathers are just a texture on plane. In Eevee render it looks good but in Cycles when there are many of feathers on one spot some of them become black.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to increase the *Max Bounces* value for *Transparent* bounces under *Light Paths* in the Cycles Render Properties. Here is another duplicate of this question with a visualization of the effect: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253028/107598

Comment: Thank you, yup it's bounces for transparency.